# Improving the performance of re.findall() being called many times and with a long pattern

Tags: python-3.x, performance, findall

I have a pd.dataFrame with about 10.000 rows, each containing a text for which I have to sum up all occurences of words, contained in a lexicon (the lexicon also has about 10k entries).

I have written code that works, but takes quite a long time on my hardware (around 6-8 Minutes) and I strongly suspect that there is a better way to do what I want to do.

The main culprit is the count_sentiments() Function:

```
def prepare_data(data:pd.DataFrame, lexicon:pd.DataFrame):
    """Calculate the needed features and write them to the provided dataframe"""

    # Filter the lexicon to create two lists of words
    positiveWords = lexicon[lexicon['sentiment'] > 0]['term'].astype(str).tolist()
    negativeWords = lexicon[lexicon['sentiment'] < 0]['term'].astype(str).tolist()

    # Create columns for our features 'pos_count', 'neg_count', 'contains_no', 'pron_count', 'contains_exclam', 'token_log'
    # The values get calculated by the applied function
    # apply() maps a function to all the members of the vector (the pd.Series object)

    # This takes around 2-3 Minutes on my hardware
    data['pos_count'] = data['review'].apply(count_sentiments, args=(positiveWords,))

    # This takes around 4-5 Minutes on my hardware
    data['neg_count'] = data['review'].apply(count_sentiments, args=(negativeWords,))

    return data

def count_sentiments(document, words):
    """Counts all positive/negative sentiment word occurences in the document"""

    sentimentSum = len(re.findall(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(words) + r')\b', document))

    return sentimentSum
```

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Without any sample data we can run, it's hard to tell. But I'd look at the `multiprocessing` package to leverage more cores. This problem seems it can be very easily split among more cores.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you for the great idea! I found this useful library (multiprocessing for pandas) https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/ and it took down the runtime to about 2 minutes.

Comment: Regexp engine are not very efficient in general. They are made for convenience but not for performance. A manual native parsing is generally at least 1 order of magnitude faster. Besides, the regexp is certainly compiled for every item which is not efficient either (if not, it is interpreted again and again which is not better). If you have a lot of words, regexp engines can be very inefficient. In this case, a trie-based parsing should be faster and also more memory efficient. Alternatively pre-compiling the regexp and using a deterministic regexp engine should speed things up a lot.